# Converting a hex-string into two different context of decimal num. in C

Tags: c

I have a string say:

```
char *hexstring = "08fc0021";
```

this is a concatenation of two information each two bytes long. 
The first two bytes of this string, ie.: 08fc corresponds to 2300 in dec.
the last 4 bytes, ie., 0021 -> 33.

My problem is to convert this string into two different variables, say:

```
int varA, varB;
```

here varA will have the number 2300, and varB = 33.

normally I would have used sscanf to convert the string into a decimal num. 
but now i have this problem of a concatenated string with two different info.

any idea suggestion how to nail this ?

thx in advance

Comment: Think about it: how to divide the string into two strings? Google for it if infeasible to do on your own.

Comment: `sscanf` it, this will give you the  32 bit number 0x08fc0021. Now you can separate this number into the two numbers 0x08fc and 0x0021. This very very basic operation is left as an exercice to the reader.

Comment: thx you two, for a fast answer. A sulotion could e.g, be to do a simple "binary and" operation (shift 4 bit to left/right..what so ever) to get the wanted info. 

What i was after is if there is a build in function that can do the work. e.g., by you defining a start memory address ...e.g, ala sscanf ..where you give a start and end address of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bitwise AND to the Rescue!**

So, doing what you require can be done using the bitwise AND opperator on the resulting 32bit number (`int`?) you get from `sscanf`.

You first get the number from the string:

```
char* hexstring = "0x08fc0021";
int num = 0;
sscanf(hexstring, "%x", &num); //put the number into num.
```

Then you get the bits you want using `&`:

```
int varA=0, varB=0;
varA = num & 0xFFFF; //will get the second half.
varB = num & 0xFFFF0000; 
varB = varB >> 16; // now you have the first half as well.
```

And there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *hexstring = "08fc0021";
    unsigned long hexnumber = 0u;
    unsigned short a = 0u;
    unsigned short b = 0u;

    /* Use sscanf() to convert the string to integer */
    sscanf(hexstring, "%x", &hexnumber);

    /* Use bitwise and to filter out the two higher bytes *
     * and shift it 16 bits right                         */
    a = ((hexnumber & 0xFFFF0000u) >> 16u);

    /* Use bitwise AND to filter out the two lower bytes */
    b = (hexnumber & 0x0000FFFFu);

    printf("0x%X 0x%X\n",a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach (bit operations):

```
char *hexstring = "08fc0021";

int aux; 
sscanf(hexstring, "%x", &aux);
printf("aux = 0x%x = %d\n", aux, aux);

int varA = (aux & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16, varB = aux & 0x0000FFFF;
printf("varA = 0x%x = %d\n", varA, varA);
printf("varB = 0x%x = %d\n", varB, varB);
```

Result:

> aux = 0x8fc0021 = 150732833
>   varA = 0x8fc = 2300
>   varB = 0x21 = 33

**EDIT:**
Or this approach (string manipulation):

```
// requires a hexstring length of 8 or more sophisticated logic
char *hexstring = "08fc0021";
int len = strlen(hexstring);

char varA[5], varB[5];
for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
{
    if(i < 4) varA[i] = hexstring[i];
    else varB[i-4] = hexstring[i];
}

varA[4] = varB[4] = '\0';

int varAi, varBi;
sscanf(varA, "%x", &varAi);
sscanf(varB, "%x", &varBi);

printf("varAi = 0x%x = %d\n", varAi, varAi);
printf("varBi = 0x%x = %d\n", varBi, varBi);
```

Same result:

> varAi = 0x8fc = 2300
>   varBi = 0x21 = 33